# Simple Java Query - Getting a Result from a Integer

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I have been set an assignment where I must find the average of a list of positive numbers enterd by the user, the amount of numbers entered is unknown. So far I have got the program to add all numbers that have been entered (the entry teminates when a user enters 0). I do not want the answer to this question on here because I am really trying to learn this fast!

I am having trouble with the while statement,

I wanted to say

`WHILE ( numberentered = 0 );`

......

but this doesnt seem to work

I originally did it like so:

```
while  ( numberentered >= 1 );

  System.out.print (numbersum);
```

but this still jumps out of the do loop when a negative number is entered.

Any idea guys.... If you understand my question but it is still worded very badly... please edit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing this?

```
while(numberEntered != 0) {
    // add it up
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (numberentered != 0) { < read new number and add it to total and ... (but you didn't want the answer...) > }
```

Comment: Ah - thank you.. re not wanting the answer, no I didnt want the answer of how to find average of numbers entered etc... but I did want this solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems like maybe you meant to do:

```
while (numberentered != 0) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Note that no semicolon is needed on the 'while' line itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I interpreted the problem statement:

"User is allowed to enter the numbers as many times but when it enters 0, the program would display the average of the numbers being entered prior to 0 and exit"

You may go this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

float no = 0;
float average = 0;
int count = 1;
   if(args.length == 0) {
     printf("No number being entered...program exits");
     System.exit(0);
     }
   if(args[0] == 0) {
     displayAverage(average);
     return;
     }
   for(count;count<args.length;count++){
   try {
            no = Float.parseFloat(args[count]);  
            if(no == 0 ) {
                break;   
              }
            average = average + no;
         } 
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
      printf("Please enter only numbers");
       }
    }
 average = average/count;
 printAverage(average);
}

private void displayAverage(float average){
 System.out.println("average is: "+ average); 
}
```

hope this may helps..